# Imprimira na tela uma mensagem ativada após uma validação

Tags: php

Eu fiz uma validação de email e cpf para ver se já estão cadastrados, existe uma forma melhor para escrever a mensagem na variável $menssage? Do que fazer a validação um por um?

```
if($emailRetornado !== null || $cpfRetornado !== null){
    if($emailRetornado !== null && $cpfRetornado !== null){
        $menssage = "EMAIL e CPF já cadastrados!";
    }
    else{
     //Ou o email foi retornado como não valido ou o cpf
         if($emailRetornado !== null){
             $menssage = "EMAIL já cadastrado!";
         }
         if($cpfRetornado !== null){
             $menssage = "CPF já cadastrado!";
         }
     }
}
echo $menssage;
```

Answer (score 1):

Partindo de que `$emailRetornado` e `$cpfRetornado` venha do banco de dados ou seja já existe um cadastro anterior dessa pessoa.

Mude a lógica para identificar qual dos campos já tem algum valor, com um if simples para cada, utilize `empty()` para verificar se valor nas variáveis. `$erros` é um array que possui as mensagens dos erros que ocorreram, então se ela for vazia o cadastro da pessoa ainda não existe, do contrário cancele o processo e exiba a mensagem de erro com um `implode()` por exemplo.

```
$emailRetornado = 'teste@teste.com';
$cpfRetornado =  '';

$erros = [];
if(!empty($emailRetornado)) $erros[] = 'EMAIL já cadastrado!';
if(!empty($cpfRetornado)) $erros[] = 'CPF já cadastrado!';

if(!empty($erros)){
    echo 'Problemas no cadastros <br>'. implode('<br>', $erros);
} else {
    //faça o tratamento do fluxo de sucesso aqui<<
}
```

[Exemplo - ideone](https://ideone.com/olftNo)